# What is meant by "carry Bit from Previous addition" in Full Adder?

Tags: digital-logic, power-electronics, logic-gates

A full adder is a combinational circuit that performs the arithmetic sum of three bits: A, B
and a carry in, C, **from a previous addition**

Q) What is the meaning of this bold text? (i.e **from a previous addition**)

I know what a carry bit is, but when it comes to Full Adder I get confused by this statement...

Comment: You can cascade several 1 bit adders to make a multi-bit adder. Except for serial adders, where a 1 bit adder is coupled with shift registers and additions are calculated over many cycles, the "normal" case is that the carry-in input is connected to another adder.

Comment: @TEMLIB: I'm really new to this lesson and not familiar with the words either... can you explain this as simple as possible???

Comment: This is exactly how it works when we learned to add in grade school.  9+6 = 5 carry the 1, then the next column you add the 1 and the other two operands A+B plus the carry in from the prior column.  You already knew how this worked...

Comment: @old_timer: Thank you very much... Now I can get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you want to add 2 numbers 2 bits each. $$AB+CD$$ First you preform B+D+0 (because you have no carry from a previous addition) and then you preform A+C+**carry from a previous addition**, i.e. from adding B+C. You do this the same way you do a long addition you did in school.

Comment: And same goes for the Half adder too right???

Comment: Half adder has only 2 inputs (only the bits you want to add without the carry). You can use it for the first operation of B+D since the carry in is 0.
You can just google the difference between half and full adder. There are many simple sources on this topic.